# How can I convert string similar to this one "May 31 2015 11:45PM" to date format in R

Tags: r, time

I am trying to convert a string similar to `"May 31 2015 11:45PM"` to a time format in R. How can I do that?

I tried this but it didn't do the job:

```
mdy_hm("May 31 2015 11:45PM")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please take the [tour] and read [MCVE]. show us your code and the result that you get.

Comment: Did you load the `lubridate` package? The code you provided works for me once I loaded the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)

s <- 'May 31 2015 11:45PM'
ts <- mdy_hm(s)

str(ts)
```

yields for me

```
 POSIXct[1:1], format: "2015-05-31 23:45:00"
```